# Visual Studio extension define dependencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dependency-management, visual-studio-extensions

How can I ensure, that my visual studio extension works on other users PC? I installed several SDKs and referenced libraries from them. I found the "Dependencies" tab in the vsixmanifest but have no clue what exactly I have do add here.

referenced libraries:

[image: referenced libraries]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a Local copy of each reference.
For every DLL or Reference, just right click on it and select Properties. In Properties Change "Copy Local" to true.

I hope this is what your problem is..

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff363239.aspx

"If a user tries to install an extension that has dependencies, the installer verifies that the required assemblies are installed on the user system. If the required assemblies are not found, Extensions and Updates displays a list of the missing assemblies."